# how to create a dataframe with equivalent frequency table

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a fake news detection model

I have been able to infer relation between the news title as against the news content
I have an existing dataframe of the following columns:

```
AUTHOR NEWS_TITLE NEWS_CREDIBILITY
```

I want to use this existing columns to create new columns as follows:

```
AUTHOR, AUTHOR_NEWS_COUNT, TOTAL_NUM_CREDIBLE_NEWS, TOTAL_NUM_NONCREDIBLE_NEWS
```

NOTE: The columns: `TOTAL_NUM_CREDIBLE_NEWS`, `TOTAL_NUM_NON_CREDIBLE_NEWS` is based on the values from the column for `NEWS_CREDIBILTY`

```
news_authors = news1['AUTHOR'].value_counts()
print(news_authors)
df[news_...
```

---

```
AUTHOR  AUTHOR_NEWS_COUNT  TOTAL_NUM_CREDIBLE_NEWS  TOTAL_NUM_NONCREDIBLE_NEWS
Pam Key        243                240                         3
David Flynn     30                 20                         10
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow,Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question but what you need may be a simple [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). I'm going to assume a function, is_credible, which takes your NEWS_CREDIBILITY and outputs TRUE or FALSE based on if it's credible. Then you need something like this:

```
df['CREDIBLE'] = df['NEWS_CREDIBILITY'].apply(is_credible)
df['NOTCREDIBLE'] = df['NEWS_CREDIBILITY'].apply(lambda x: not is_credible(x))
```

this creates a boolean column of credibility and its opposite (there is probably a more elegant way to do this, sorry!)

Then you can do:

```
per_author_df = df.groupby('AUTHOR').agg({'NEWS_TITLE':'count','CREDIBLE':'sum','NOTCREDIBLE':'sum'})
```

This basically groups by author and performs the following operations on those three colums. NEWS_TITLE becomes count of news articles, and since in sum TRUE=1 and FALSE=0 the two other columns are a count of credible or incredible news.

EDIT: As I said earlier, you need a function like `is_credible` that tells you what is credible based on your NEWS_CREDIBILITY column. For example, if NEWS_CREDIBILITY is a score and having over 80 means you are credible, it would be:

```
def is_credible(cred_score):
    if cred_score >= 80:
        return TRUE
    else:
        return FALSE
```

You need to adapt this to your NEWS_CREDIBILITY column - I don't even know what data type that carries.

Comment: Thanks for the input. i tried using the code u drop but i receive this error. NameError: name 'is_credible' is not defined

Comment: Please see the edit - you need to make that function yourself based on your NEWS_CREDIBILITY column